# Where is the sourcecode for curl_easy_perform() in libcurl?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I cannot find the source code for this important function in the libcurl source tree. Nor do I find a definition of this function in curl.h. Neither a search of the linux kernel github source nor several google searches yields anything.

curl_easy_perform() has to be defined and implemented somewhere, or at least defined by way of some macro(?), but, while numerous examples are given of this function being called, I have found nothing of its implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: What does a 3rd party library have to do with the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in [`easy.c`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/4f45240bc84a9aa648c8f7243be7b79e9f9323a5/lib/easy.c)

```
/*
 * curl_easy_perform() is the external interface that performs a blocking
 * transfer as previously setup.
 */
CURLcode curl_easy_perform(CURL *easy)
{
  return easy_perform(easy, FALSE);
}
```

I found this by going to the cURL github repository and putting `CURLcode curl_easy_perform` into the search field (just searching for `curl_easy_perform` has too many hits because it finds all the testing and documentation code that refers to the function, not just the definitions).

`easy_perform()`, which does all the real work, is defined right before it.

Comment: Excellent, Barmar! Thanks a lot.